How do i customize selected NavigationBarItem?

1)How to remove selection indicator, located around hello ?
2)How to change hello's color, after selecting it ?

There is a paramater for NavigationBarItem called colors and you can specify the color of selected and text color
NavigationBarItem(selected, onClick, icon, NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(...)
fun colors(
        selectedIconColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        selectedTextColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        indicatorColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        unselectedIconColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        unselectedTextColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        disabledIconColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        disabledTextColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    )


Do you know how to paint a selected icon and leave not selected icon not painted ?
